# Angular 2: Undefined route parameter value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and please correct me if my understanding in terminology are incorrect.

Working on a sample app where I need to read the route parameter value in child component . I am able to print the "Params" object but unable to extract the data in it. Just pasting my code so that I can give more details :

Customer Details component:

```
 ngOnInit() {

        this.route.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
           console.log( params);
        console.log("Id value" + params['id']);

       if (1) {
    this._custServ.getCustomerDetailsById(1)
      .subscribe((customer: ICustomer) => {
        this.customer = customer;
       //s console.log(customer.id);

      });
  }
});
```

}

---

Url I am accessing : http://localhost:4200/customers/1/details

---

Google Chrome Console:

[messages on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ympC2.png)

I have tried to get the parameters value since a day but no luck. Could you please guide me in this case.

Thanks
Prashant

---

Updated code as per the guidance from Sujeethan but now I am receiving id as null value. full code of the component below.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoCVa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow your console showes the correct value, it just that your if condition is wrong, you should assign the value and check in if condition

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log("Id value" + params['id']);
        let id = params["id"];
        if (id ==="1") {
            this._custServ.getCustomerDetailsById(1)
                .subscribe((customer: ICustomer) => {
                    this.customer = customer;
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan ,  I updated the code but I am now receiving null value.                                          Message on console: "Id value null "

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, i used your same code but still seeing id value as undefined. Any thoughts whether I am missing anything?

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted in VS editor and checked the results.. Unfortunately it is still undefined value.

Comment: with the latest image you provided i see still if(1)

Comment: Thank you Sanjeethan for your help :) The issue was a typo mistake in the routing file : I had put a space after id and  Sanjeethan kindly had a screen share session with me and identified and fixed as below. Silly mistake but learnt a lesson:)                                                                                 {
  path :'customers/:id' ,
  component : NewCusomerComponentComponent,
  children : [{path :'details' ,component : CustomerDetailsComponent}] 
}